# How does Hadoop transfer user-defined parameters to tasks?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

In Hadoop, how does it transfer user's configuration parameter to the task? For example,

```
conf.set("myparameter", "somestring")
```

then I can get the parameter in the mapreduce by 
`conf.get("myparameter")`.

Is it through `Serializable`? and how about the other parameters, such as such as the classes, e.g., `job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);` etc.

Comment: Please format your code properly the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration will be serialized into XML and uploaded HDFS.
Each task is going to copy the xml to the local FS.

The class files are in the jar you provide within the job. The class names are put into the configuration, on the task side the classes are instantiated with reflection.

This is the reason why e.G. Writables need to have a default constructor.

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient#submitJobInternal();` Which is going to do this: `Path submitJobFile = new Path(submitJobDir, "job.xml");` and later `job.writeXml(out);`, where job is a `JobConf`

Comment: Thnx +1 - there's always something new to learn about Hadoop :) BTW, it's JobSubmitter#submitJobInternal().